# "KOTLIN" Saving PDF to Media.Downloads creates pdf with 0 Byte

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, storage, media

I am trying to save a pdf that I created in-app programmatically to a specified directory in Downloads. Everything is working except the pdf size. It creates a pdf with 0 bytes and it's impossible to open it.

Here is my code (Sorry, i am a beginner):

```
        val document = PdfDocument()
        val pageInfo = PageInfo.Builder(1080, 1920, 1).create()
        val page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
        val canvas = page.canvas
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.RED
        canvas.drawText("Hallo", 80f, 50f, paint)
        document.finishPage(page)
       
        val resolver = contentResolver
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "test")
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + "xyz")
        val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)
        // You can use this outputStream to write whatever file you want:
        val outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
        document.close()
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Android.  (This is Android, isn't it?)  But it looks like you're creating the PDF document, creating a stream, but not actually writing the document to the stream…

Comment: thanks, it sounds logical but as I wrote, I am a beginner and don't know how to do it. Maybe there is something that will help me :) and yes it's android, Kotlin